# “Some” vs “some of” with adjective

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

Suppose an application user selects certain objects and then attempts to perform an operation involving them.

Which of the following responses is correct, and why?

> 1. Operation is not supported **by some** selected objects
> 2. Operation is not supported **by some of** selected objects

It would make sense with "some of the", but does it also work without "of" completely?

Comment: I think it would be unnecessary to add *of* without also using *the*. You could debate that *objects* is plural, and therefore no article is necessary, but *some* makes it a defined group of sorts, so I would use *the*. And honestly it sounds more natural.

Comment: We need to understand the context better. This looks like documentation for software or perhaps an error message produced by software. Please explain more about what you are trying to say. Both **some selected** and **some of the selected** may be appropriate, depending upon the context.

Comment: It's when user selects some objects in GUI and then clicks a button which triggers an operation on them.

Comment: Without a determiner such as ***this*** before ***operation***, your text isn't really a valid English sentence anyway. It's just a "terse computer error message" equivalent to "newspaper headlinese", so you can't really talk about there being a "correct" version (such text has no particular relation to standard grammar, so you probably *shouldn't* think in terms of this example teaching you anything about correct grammar in any other contexts). But your text would usually be rendered as ***Operation not supported** [by some selected objects]* by most native speaker programmers.

Comment: I have an intuitive doubt whether it's correct to say that the operation is actually *supported by* any of the objects. Might it be *not supported for one or more selected objects?* Or *when using one or more . . .?*

Comment: _Operation not supported **for** selected objects._ This has become the accepted form in which such errors are expressed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree, *except* that I think there is still a grammar to headlinese, computer error messages, etc.; for example, although "operation complete" and "the operation is complete" are both fine, ?"operation is complete" seems marginal and \*"the operation complete" is flat-out wrong, IMHO.

Comment: @ruakh: Well, yes. But I think ELL shouldn't be in the business of advising nns how to write computer status messages. I also think P. E. Dant is quite right re ***for***. Only really geeky programmers would use ***by*** because that implies the selected objects themselves can *do* things (such as supporting certain operations). Non-specialists would more naturally think in terms of the *computer* (the "entity" generating the message) being able perform the necessary operations *with* the selected objects. But is this a matter for ELL to go into? I don't really think so.

Answer (score 1):

*Some* can be a determiner and a pronoun.  So both are valid grammatically.

> Operation is not supported by some selected objects
>
> Operation is not supported by some of the selected objects

They also are equivalent in meaning here.  The second sentence is placing distinctness on a group of "the selected objects", somewhat implying that there is another category of objects (possibly other than *unselected* objects) that are not to be considered in this statement.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple rule:

> Before a *noun* with a *determiner* *(articles, demonstratives and possessive pronouns)*, we use **some of**. If there is *no determiner* we use **some**. ([EnglishGrammar.com](https://www.englishgrammar.org/some-and-some-of/))

- ...**some** selected objects
- ...**some of the** selected objects *(**the** - definite article)*

From the NGram we can see that "**some selected**" is the common way:
[image]

As a bonus:

> **Some of** is also used before a pronoun.
>
> - **Some of us** want a new system. *(NOT **Some us** want a new system.)*